# TFS SQL Server Report builder - Trouble finding Test plan ID parameter syntax

Tags: testing, tfs, report

Modifying canned TFS reports with default values for date, iteration and Test Plan (for embedded burndown reporting against a specific project) 
Another article on this site led to a great report to pull the IterationID syntax that is needed within the parameter field (AreasAndInterations.RDL on OneDrive).

I'm trying to locate a similar report (or a query) that will provide the syntax and values needed for a default "Test Plan" to load within the RDL report.
Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: What's the detail trouble with finding Test plan ID? Could you explain more clear and suggest you to provide a related screenshot.

Comment: I know the ID and the name for the test plan.  I'm having a problem with the syntax or format needed in order to populate the Test Plan ID parameter field:  The default syntax is:  [Test Plan].[Test Plan ID].[All] - trying to replace the [All] with correct format for a specific test plan id.  obvious replacements (putting ID in for the the word All) have not worked.  iteration/area path required a more complex format.